# SQL code to find a number that contains only a unique digit

Tags: teradata

Hope someone can help me out:
I need to write a code that will tell me if a number contains only the digit 9.
For example: 9, 99, 999, 9999999999

I think you got it :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the column numeric or a varchar?

Answer (score 0):

This works for both varchar and any integer:

```
where trim(trailing '9' from col) = ''
```

Fails for decimals, but could easily be modified.